# Whats the simplest way to run a update and select query as one query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two queries which I want to run at the same time from my php script.One is a update query and the other is a select query.
This is the update query

```
UPDATE stock_list SET qty=qty -1 where itembarcode="BRMS01";
```

And this my select query

```
SELECT itembarcode,description,weight,making FROM stock_list  WHERE itembarcode="BRMS01"
```

I tried something like

```
UPDATE stock_list SET qty=qty -1 AND SELECT itembarcode,description,weight,making FROM stock_list  WHERE itembarcode="BRMS01";
```

And I get an error like - (

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SELECT itembarcode,description,weight,making FROM stock_list
>   WHERE itembarcode=' at line 1

)
Any help is appreciated.Thank you:)

Comment: no its not possible, you want to update a row, and then you want to select something this is not allowed in a single query.

Comment: Note that in ANSI SQL double quotes are for identifiers, like `"column-name"`,  and single quotes are for string literals, e.g. `'BRMS01'`.

Comment: when you say same time can't you just execute both in a single transaction?

Answer (score 2):

Transactions are your friend here.

if you do

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE stock_list SET qty=qty -1 where itembarcode='BRMS01';
SELECT itembarcode,description,weight,making FROM stock_list  WHERE itembarcode='BRMS01';
COMMIT;
```

This would do your update operation, then run your select query at the same time (rather than doing one, then the other.

EDIT:

To clarify how it should be written for the OP's situation

```
mysqli_query($con,"START TRANSACTION;  UPDATE stock_list SET qty=qty -1 where itembarcode='BRMS01'; SELECT itembarcode,description,weight,making FROM stock_list  WHERE itembarcode='BRMS01'; COMMIT; ");
```

This is the transaction based query you need to run. all on one execution, not multiple.

Comment: Or you have to use a stored procedure saved in the DB

Comment: I'm not sure this is what OP was asking for, with "as one query".

Comment: This is a single transaction, which functions as a single query. if each one were run without hte transaction you would have potentially different results.